# Give tt_content element some header info in page view

Tags: typo3, extbase

When I look at a page in page view in the typo3 backend, I want to add some information to each tt_content element, like write the section_frame type in the header of the draggable item. Like here: [image]

Can I add Information in the grey bar, like a title or something? How can this be done? I'm at a loss, I don't even really know what to google, because I don't know what that thing is called in typo3.

Any, ANY hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grey header is reserved for icons and you can not change it, on your screenshot the **Image Slider** is the header of CE, and it can be manipulated by the
`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']` hook.

It's quite busy process, so I just can link to the nice blog post by Steffen Müller: https://stmllr.net/blog/customizing-preview-widgets-in-the-typo3-page-module/

Comment: @stmllr, Steffen I'm sorry for typo in your name :)